# ReflectionException : Class /ModelGenerator does not exist [PhpUnit newbie]

Tags: php, reflection, phpunit

I have a protected method in class ModelGenerator from the file:

```
C:\src\x\y\ModelGenerator.php
```

The test for it is in class ModelGeneratorTest from the file:

```
C:\test\x\y\ModelGeneratorTest.php
```

ReflectionException : Class /ModelGenerator does not exist when executing

```
   public function testGetTable()
{

    $method = new \ReflectionMethod("ModelGenerator", 'getTable');
    $method->setAccessible(true);
    echo $method->invoke(ModelGenerator);
}
```

I also used:

```
namespace x\y;
```

Solved: The quotes were the problem

Comment: ModelGenerator in ReflectionMethod is without its namespace. You need to add a full classname to the string. Usually you don't test protected methods with reflection.

Comment: ok, thanks, but then, what do i use and can you help with the example?. The file system is different also

Comment: Usually if you have to test a protected method it's a sign for a dependency and need to be moved into an own class and need to be injected into your Generator. Simple protected and private methods are tested with the public method using the protected/private ones.